# Workflow foundation, Transactions and Bookmarks

Tags: transactions, workflow, workflow-foundation

We are developing an application using Workflow Foundation 4. 
We expect to use multiple activities each doing database updates within a transaction. 
We would also like to pause and resume the workflow. 
The pauses may be long-running.
To ensure **consistency** we would like to make sure there is a bookmark created regarding where to resume the workflow before committing the transactions.
Is this at all possible? Or any other suggestions on how to implement this well?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

WF4 has a `TransactionScope` activity, which you can use to perform database calls. However, it does not support creating bookmarks within the `TransactionScope` sequence. A work around would be to have staging tables for temporarily storing in-progress data for a long running process that the workflow can read from when its resumed. Once everything is settled, you can write the data from the staging tables to your real storage.